# Index of JSON Array Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using this library to parse an API endpoint that returns an array: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

I am grabbing an array fetched from a JSON response and I am trying to feed it into a table.

Right after my class in my view controller is declared, I have

```
var fetched_data:JSON = []
```

Inside of my viewDidLoad method:

```
let endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/api")
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint!)
        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        fetched_data = json["posts"].arrayValue
```

To feed the table, I have:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.fetched_data[indexPath.row]
        return cell      
    }
```

I am getting this error, when trying to set the cell textLabel:

```
Cannot subscript a value of a type ‘JSON’ with an index type of ‘Int’
```

**How do I do this properly and get this to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `fetched_data` as `JSON`

```
var fetched_data:JSON = []
```

but you are assigning `Array` to it:

```
fetched_data = json["posts"].arrayValue
```

Lets change the type to array of `AnyObject`:

```
var fetched_data: Array<AnyObject> = []
```

and then assigning should be like this (we have `[AnyObject]` so we need to cast):

```
if let text = self.fetched_data[indexPath.row] as? String {
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
}
```

**Edit:** You also need to remember to assign correct `Array`, by doing `arrayObject` instead of `arrayValue`:

```
fetched_data = json["posts"].arrayObject
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, in my vieDidLoad method, I am getting: Cannot assign value of type ‘[JSON]’ to type ‘Array<String>’

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, I really appreciate it!